# How to rename all system generate constraint names in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to change all current constraint names like `[PK__Features__3214EC06F2EA1DA2]` to more readable one like `[PK__Features]`?

I want to rename all available constraints and make SQL server ready to deploy.

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Use sp_rename to rename the constraints. You will have to query all of them and establish a "unique" new name for them.

Comment: And learn from the lesson; name your constraints when you create them in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the best solution. I used this piece of code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE @Rename NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE RenameCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename ''[' + c.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.CONSTRAINT_NAME + ']'', ''PK_' + c.TABLE_NAME
       + ''', ''OBJECT'''
FROM TableNameHere.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS c
WHERE c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
      AND c.TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME;
OPEN RenameCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM RenameCursor
INTO @Rename;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql @Rename;
    FETCH NEXT FROM RenameCursor
    INTO @Rename;
END;
CLOSE RenameCursor;
DEALLOCATE RenameCursor;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You just need to replace `TableNameHere` with your destination table name. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by using this script to generate `exec sp_rename` scripts for every constraint that is named by the system - it even gives you a more readable name that's guaranteed to be unique - but not as readable as a hand-picked one.

Hopefully, you won't have to edit too much of them.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT object_id, is_system_named
    FROM sys.default_constraints
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT object_id, is_system_named
    FROM sys.check_constraints
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT object_id, is_system_named
    FROM sys.key_constraints 
)

SELECT 'EXEC sp_rename @objname = '''
        +  o.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS -- old name
        + ''', @newname = '''
        + RTRIM(o.type) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS -- start the new name with the type of the constraint
        + '_'+ object_name(o.parent_object_id) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS -- add the table name it belongs to
        + CASE 
            WHEN o.Type = 'PK' THEN ''';' -- if it's the primary key, we're done
            ELSE +'_'+  CAST(o.object_id as varchar(11)) +''';' -- otherwise, add the object id, to ensure uniqueness.
         END
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN CTE
    ON o.object_id = CTE.object_id
WHERE is_system_named = 1
```

The result will look like this (of course, names will be different):

```
EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'PK__sysdiagr__C2B05B615A3AB936', @newname = 'PK_sysdiagrams';
EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'DF__dtpropert__versi__77BFCB91', @newname = 'D_dtproperties_2009058193';
```

Comment: Nice but what's up with all the `COLLATE`?

Comment: @CervEd It's been a long time since I wrote this answer, I don't remember why I thought the `collate` was needed. Perhaps you don't actually need it.

Comment: It was probably to work around the collation of sys tables https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118162/223418